# How many Master databases should you have across all environments?

Tags: setup, infrastructure

This is going to sound like a real newbie question but is something I can't get my head round in terms of how our real world setup compares to what was taught in Sitecore training.

So - in the simplest, single environment/instance, example: you have **1 Master** & **1 Web**, new items are added to Master and then, to make them show on the site, they are published to Web.

Real world: we have 3 environments (DEV, UAT and PROD) which each have 1 Master & 1 Web. New *content* is added on PROD Master and published to PROD Web. New *functionality* is added on DEV Master and published to DEV Web and then, once signed off, is recreated on UAT(or PROD) Master and published to UAT(or PROD) Web. There are then, semi-regular, backups made of PROD Master & Web which are restored to DEV and UAT.

In my mind (and from what I, possibly mistakenly, remember from training) I am thinking that, in the real world, it should be possible for ... DEV to have 1 Master & 1 Web but UAT and PROD should each only have 1 Web. All new content/functionality is added to DEV Master and then published to DEV Web, UAT Web and then PROD Web.

Am I missing something obvious here ?

Answer (score 3):

In my current environment we have the following (Sitecore XM 10.2):

- **DEV** : Configured as a standalone instance where a single instance of MSSQL hosts all databases. This is running on the local workstation.
- **INT** : The first integrated environment configured as a standalone instance like **DEV**.
- **TST** : Environment that closely mimics the production configuration. One MSSQL instance for the **ContentManagement** role and another for the **ContentDelivery** role. The CM role has a Core and Master database. The CD role has a Core and Web database. In my case, the Core db is NOT shared between CM/CD.
- **PRD** : Configured like TST but more secure.

When it comes to moving changes between environments you'll want to consider which are part of the CI/CD pipeline (i.e. code, config, items) and what is content managed by authors that could be synced across environments as needed (e.g. home and descendants and media items). Remember that this is a CMS and content items in lower environments should not matter much; although if you decide to create content in lower environments to speed up the process then you can pick which method is best to move up through environments.

Each environment could/should have a single master db that corresponds with the **ContentManagement** role. The publishing targets (e.g. Internet aka web) are then largely based on your business needs. Sometimes you see publishing targets for different geographical locations or perhaps line of business.

Comment: just curious on the use case where Core is not shared between CM and CD. how would one manage users in this case? Do you have some sort of master/slave architecture between Core databases of CM and CD?

Comment: Brochure websites don't need to track users.

Answer (score 0):

Each environment should have it's own set of Master and Web databases.

If you follow the set up you have suggested with a single Master database with a target for Dev, UAT and Prod, this will not allow you test any of your changes without causing huge problems. Think about updates to a set of templates, and the corresponding code which is required. And any content updates or changes, even testing the site with dummy data. This becomes a problem and you would then have to manage not publishing those to UAT or Prod.

You can set up an additional "Web" database for each environment, which will act as a [preview publishing target](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/users/102/sitecore-experience-platform/setting-up-a-preview-publishing-target.html), but that is different scenario from what you have asked.

If you want to move packages of content or items between environments you also have the option to create package using the Package Designer and then install in the other environments using the Installation Wizard. You do not necessarily need to recreate them from scratch on each environment.

Comment: Thanks for that - and in a way your examples/rational make sense though I don't see a real problem with dummy data, etc on DEV and nowhere else. Sure, the deployment of content changes to UAT and PROD might be harder but it just sounds so much more sensible than "everything you have done, for this new feature, on DEV ? Now do it all again and UAT and PROD rather than just publishing DEV to UAT and PROD".

Answer (score 0):

For each of the environment we must have **1 - Master** database but we can have **multiple Web** databases.

**For example**: Suppose you a tenant for China region. As per China policy, all content specific to China regsion, you must have to keep data inside the China. So you will be creating a seperate database inside the China and will create a Web database for China region. After that you must have to create a publishing target for China region so that after publishing China content, it can go to the **China Web** database.

So, based on your requirement you can create multiple Web databases but you must have to create a seperate publishing target.

Hoping this will help you.

Thanks.